# Javascript large integer changing to even

Tags: javascript, numbers

Hopefully someone can help as this is driving me nuts.  I'm using alert as an example to abstract from my code.

```
alert(10153507376200685); //returns 10153507376200684
alert(10153507376200684); //returns 10153507376200684
alert(10153507376200687); //returns 10153507376200688
```

What is wrong with the odd number ending/.

Comment: [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Comment: Is it possible to output that value as a string? E.g. alert('10153507376200685');